# Why does crosstalk occur in high speed design only?

Tags: rf, emc

I am studying to get a job in EMC and my exams are coming soon.

I am currently studying "high speed design" techniques, and I stumbled upon this thing called "crosstalk."

I know about coupling. There are 3 types of coupling "inductive" "capacitive" "common impedance" coupling.

Why does crosstalk occurs at high frequencies? What is the relation between frequency and crosstalk?

Comment: It doesn't only occur in high speed design.  It can occur at any frequency.  It's just a really important consideration in high speed design.

Comment: Why it is important consideration in high speed design?

Comment: It was annoying to hear your neighbors in the background of your telephone call (cross talk in analog telephone systems, low frequency audio signals.)  It's a disaster when your high speed digital protocol "hears" things from other signal paths.

Comment: Common impedance coupling can be harmful even at DC. This is why for ex. many variable resistance sensors are connected with 4 wires - 2 for DC supply and 2 for actual measuring. The sensor has only 2 terminals, so each terminal has a sense wire to the actual preamp or signal evaluation circuit and another which brings the needed DC current. With 2 wires the DC voltage drop in the wires would cause wrong measurement result.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why crosstalk problems mostly appear at high frequencies is because the parasitics are more important at high frequencies.

Consider a situation where you have 10 pF between two signal lines, each of which have a ~50 Ohm impedance. For a 1 GHz interference, the coupling between the lines is ~15 Ohms. Therefore, the interference will remain to a large fraction on the victim line. In the same situation, if the interference is at 1 MHz, the interference has to "penetrate" a 15 kOhm impedance to reach the victim at then gets flushed away with a low 50 Ohm node impedance, so it will be stronly attenuated.

Similar arguments can be derived for inductive coupling. The tiny stray inductances become more influential at high frequencies.

Common impedance coupling *can* rise at high frequencies because the e.g. Ground plane impedance rises. This would be the situation if chips are grouped badly. In practise with good layout, common impedance coupling can become less of a problem at high frequencies, because currents through the plane are more confined to the signal traces and therefore interfere less with neighboring signals using the same plane for return.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does crosstalk occurs at high frequencies? What is the relation between frequency and crosstalk?

As JRE has pointed out in his [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/563600/why-does-crosstalk-occur-in-high-speed-design-only#comment1471975_563600), crosstalk does not have to occur at only high frequencies.

Crosstalk is highly dependent on the \$dt\$ of the source signal, rather than the frequency (at least, not directly). Here's the formula for capacitively induced current and coupled voltage:

$$
\mathrm{
I_C= C\ \frac{dV_s}{dt} \\
\\ \
V_C=I_C\ Z_o
}
$$

As can be seen from the formulas above, the lower the \$dt\$, the higher the amount of coupled voltage due to the crosstalk.

For digital signals, \$dt\$ is the rise time (T<sub>r</sub>) of the source signal. It's obvious that the T<sub>r</sub> becomes lower and lower for high frequencies (e.g. 10 MHz) and thus a bigger problem. That's why the crosstalk is one big issue that should be taken care of.

But even if you keep the frequency low (e.g. 19.2kHz for UART), crosstalk can become a big problem if T<sub>r</sub> is a few nanoseconds.